# Getting No template found for FormsController#show, rendering head :no_content when trying to refresh a div with a partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to refresh a div in a partial in rails and am getting an error.

I set up a test page to keep everything simple and help troubleshooting.

It is a Rails 5 project.

My testzzz.html.erb is

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("/forms/test_partial");
       alert("here");
    });
});
<% end %>

<h3>This is a test of whatever</h3>

<button>Get External Content</button>

<hr>
<div id="div1">
    Hi there 
       <%= render "test_partial"  %>
</div>
```

That results in the following (Formatting isn't showing of course)

```
This is a test of whatever
Get External Content
Hi there
This is a test This is Rails Partial
The current time is 2018-03-01 15:15:02 -0500 
Random number 30
```

That would seem to indicate that I can render test_partial.

My partial, _test_partial.html.erb is

```
<h1>This is a test This is Rails Partial</h1>

The current time is <%= Time.now %> <br>
Random number <%= rand(10...42) %>
<hr>
```

My thought is that if is actually refreshing, then the current time and random number will change.

I do not have anything in my routes for the partial

My forms controller has

```
def test_partial
  render "/forms/_test_partial", 
          layout: false
end
```

The show def is just

```
def show
end
```

However, based on other things I tried, I don't think that is the problem but I could be wrong.

If I look in the terminal, I see the following when I click the button

```
Started GET "/forms/test_partial" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-01 14:54:53 -0500
Processing by FormsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"test_partial"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
No template found for FormsController#show, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

I have tried a lot of variations of /forms/test_partial, test_partial, forms/test_partial etc. but it seems I can't get it working right.

Comment: this is an old pattern, but you might need to investigate into format.js response available in rails (ex. https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails). you render a kind of js-in-erb but that's a template; not a partial. im' unsure you can render a partial from a controller without hacking thing a bit

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, js is expecting there to be an actual URL called `/forms/test_partial` - if you want that to work in Rails then you need to set up a route that will render that partial for you.

I'm assuming you'd make a route for `forms#test_partial`

Then in your controller, you need to remember that you are already in the context of `forms`, so you don't need to pass `/forms/test_partial` in the render here... The render of a controller is *different* to the render inside a template.

A simple option for you would be:

```
def test_partial
  render :test_partial, layout: false
end
```

plus a top-level erb file `/forms/test_partial.html.erb` that just includes the partial you want eg:

```
<%= render :test_partial %>
```

(remember you are already in the context of `forms` so shouldn't need to specify the full partial-path. However if this is shared across multiple controllers, then you might need to be explicit)